# How to display curve without exponential peaks

Tags: logarithms, visualization

My input data normally contains values in [-1,+1], but contains exponential peaks. I'd like to use logarithms to reduce the peaks, but don't know how as my data contains negative values. Is there some function similar to `log` that I can use, or how does one normally do this kind of thing?

Comment: You might shift the data into the positive range. But this only works if you can pre determine a minimal data value.

Comment: @mvw: My peaks are only on the positive side, so this is a working solution for me in my scenario. I had hoped for a more generic solution, but will use this for now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of the suggestion by [Hagen Knaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1997516/72158) might do the trick:

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{|x|}}$

The peaks will be there, but reduced. If your data is *actually* exponential in nature (very uncommon), it won't work of course. Otherwise you might get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation seems to suggest that you don't really want to remove the peaks, that is remove the corresponding data like one sometimes does with outliers, but you want to rescale in a nonlinear way.
You could use something like $f(x)=\mathrm{sign}(x)\log(|x|+1)$, where $\mathrm{sign}$ is the sign of $x$.

Another possibility, which always yields values in $[-1,1]$ is given by $g(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$.

Of course a main issue is the amount of contraction that is acceptable for the "normal" data. $g$ is worse than $f$ in that respect.

Comment: You're right about that scaling. Your solution seems to have the draw-back of negating values like +0.1 and -0.1, or in fact all values between (-1,+1). A sine curve comes out like [this](//imgur.com/sD08Kgx), which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, that looks funny and wasn't my intention. What about the corrected formula?

Comment: I simplified it. That's better, but a little bit funny as it truncates all peaks to ~1. Perhaps in combination with something... don't know what exactly though! :)